# Sequelizer - Unexpected token z in JSON at position 65

Tags: json, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

hope someone can help me. After running the Sequelize model generator, I succesfully generate my model and database migration. However, when I run the sequlize db:migrate command, I get this error

`ERROR: Error reading "src\db\config\config.json". Error: SyntaxError: C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Federico - Bootcamp\bloccit\src\db\config\config.json: Unexpected token z in JSON at position 65` (see full code below)

[image]

But when I go and look at the config.json file (see below), I can't find anything at line 65... the code actually finishes at row 27... so I'm stuck from finding the solution to this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Default sequelize-cli will open file at config/config.json. Document at [here](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/migrations.html#installing-cli)

Let try option **--config**

```
sequelize-cli db:migrate --env development --config ./src/db/config/config.json
```